# Why local package widgets not showing up time to time?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a ui package, this package simply contains some(10+) widgets and they are all just a widgets. None of them some complex controller or etc so when I use them, I can't miss the something like initializers or etc.

So my problem is, after the installation an app(which is contains a lot of witget from that package) everything working correctly like the image.

[image]

But if I change the current app on android/real device(and without debug mode), like switching the chrome and spend some time at the browser, after returning the app, all widgets showing off, they are simply dissappering. Like the image;

[image]

So my question is simple, why can it be happen? By the way, the divider as shown the middle of the page,is not part of the package, it is located in app/lib folder.

and lastly, I don't give any change but I have 57 svg file in the package but I am not call all of them at same time and their total size just 833,5kb, but maybe it can be related?

I don't have any native knowledge but if anyone can point me some tips, I will be glad.

Comment: Can you provide your `flutter doctor` please ?

Comment: Without chrome-develop for the web(cannot find chrome executable at google-chrome), all of the logs seems alright(check marked). @HantsanialaEléo

Comment: What version of flutter is it ?

Comment: flutter:3.0.2 - channel stable, dart: 2.17.3

Comment: I'm not sur if it's the same problem but I've fixed mine with upgrading the `ext.kotlin_version = 1.7.0` inside `android/build.gradle`.

Comment: @HantsanialaEléo thank u for your answer hantsanialaeleo but why it can be happen, do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure myself either, maybe a bug. It happen to me only on release mode.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if it's a bug related to the new version of Flutter (3.0.2) but upgrading `ext.kotlin_version` inside `android/build.gradle` to **1.7.0** do the trick.